# Move Child Rows to new Parent FK ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child, relationship

SQL Server 2008.

I have a parent row with pk id 1. While blocking all other DB users (this is a cleanup operation so resource contention is not an issue), I would like to insert a new row, then take all of the child rows and change their fk column to the new row. With the below DDL for example, I would like to insert a new row and give all of the #chi.parid values a value of '3' so they would essentially now belong to the new row so the old one can be deleted.

Help!

```
create table #par ( parid int identity(1,1) , note varchar(8) )
create table #chi ( chiid int identity(1,1) , parid int , thing varchar(8) )
insert into #par values ( 'note1' )
insert into #par values ( 'note2' )
insert into #chi values ( 1 , 'a' )
insert into #chi values ( 1 , 'b' )
insert into #chi values ( 1 , 'c' )
```

Comment: Does SQL Server have 'ON UPDATE CASCADE' as part of the key definition? If it has, that'd be the way to go.

Comment: @Brian - Yes it does. @ScSub any reason why you can't use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the input. It appears I "can't" do a set-based operation on this with SQL Svr 2008, so I did RBAR solution with a loop (I think it performs better than a cursor). Anyone who can comment on making this safer with try..catch or enlighten me more on doing this in a set, please comment. :)

Thanks.

```
    Select 
                [parid]
            ,   [name]
    Into    #redo
    From    partable 
    Where   DateDiff( Hour , donewhen ,SysDateTimeOffset() ) > 23
Begin Transaction
Declare @rows int  = ( Select COUNT(*) From #redo )
Declare @parid int 
Create Clustered Index redoix on #redo([parid]) With FillFactor = 100
While @rows > 0
Begin
    Select Top 1 @parid = [parid] from #redo Order By parid Asc

        Insert partable 
            (
                [name]
            )
        Select 
                [name]      
        From #redo 
        Where parid = @parid
        Update chitable
            Set parid = Scope_Identity()
            Where   parid = @parid
        Delete From partable
            Where   parid = @parid

    Delete from #redo where [parid] = @parid 
    Set @rows  = ( Select COUNT(*) From #redo )
End
Commit Transaction
```

Comment: You are not getting it.  You **can** use set-based commands.  But the Surrogates the `Id` columns prevent that.  Reference the real keys in the where clause, not the surrogates.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to shun surrogate keys in favour of natural keys or FKs; also, I would avoid `IDENTITY` for artificial identifiers. To be honest, I find myself in the minority and have often wondered myself how to achieve bulk inserts with `IDENTITY` FKs.

As per Alan Barker's answer, you can utilize `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` but only if you want to do this RBAR (row by agonizing row). You say, "this is a cleanup operation" so perhaps a procedural solution is acceptable.

The way I've got around the problem myself is to manually generate a sequence of potential `IDENTITY` values (e.g. in a staging table) then use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT TargetTable ON` to force the values in. Obviously, I need to ensure the proposed values will not actually be in use by the time the `INSERT` occurs so all other users will still need to be blocked.

A couple of things to watch. Sometimes the obligatory `UNIQUE` constraint on the `IDENTITY` column is missing so you may need to check there are no collisions yourself. Also, I've found that the kind of person who likes surrogates can get a bit 'flustered' when the values aren't sequential (and in the positive range!) or, much worse, there is application logic that relies on a perfect sequence or has exposed the  `IDENTITY` values to the business (in which case 'faking' enterprise key values such as order numbers can fall fowl of real life auditors).

EDIT: reading an answer to another SO question this morning reminded me about SQL Server 2008's `OUTPUT` clause to capture all the auto-generated `IDENTITY` values in a table e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE #InsertedBooks
(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, -- surrogate
 isbn_13 CHAR(13) NOT NULL UNIQUE -- natural key
);

WITH InsertingBooks (isbn_13)
AS 
(
 SELECT '9781590597453'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '9780596523060'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '9780192801425'
)
INSERT INTO Books (isbn_13)
  OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.isbn_13   -- <--
  INTO #InsertedBooks (ID, isbn_13)      -- <--
SELECT isbn_13
  FROM InsertingBooks;

INSERT INTO AnotherTable...
SELECT T1.ID, ...
  FROM #InsertedBooks AS T1...;

DROP TABLE #InsertedBooks
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want an update, such as :

```
UPDATE chi SET parid = 2 WHERE parid = 1
```

FKeys shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: Sorry I did not specify before, I need a fully set-based solution. The number of parent rows that need re-inserting and child-changing number in the dozens. I can do a single update without a problem. My problem is keeping the old parid, creating the new parid, doing the update in the child from old->new parid. After that I can delete the old parid. I'm stuck!

Thanks

Comment: @Snowy. This **is** a set based solution. Write one dozen INSERT new_parent statements, then write UPDATE statements. Or put those one doze old/new values in a temp table, and write one INSERT/UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Kalium's solution, you could use the SCOPE_IDENTITY() function to retrieve the IDENTITY value of the last table insert.

```
begin tran    

   insert into #par values ('New Parent')  

   update #chi set parid= SCOPE_IDENTITY()

   delete from #par where parid = <OLD_ID>    

commit
```

This way you could code this as a Stored Procedure to do the whole thing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CleanUp @newNote varchar(8), @IDToDelete int 
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRAN

    INSERT INTO #par VALUES (@newNote)      
    UPDATE #chi SET parid= SCOPE_IDENTITY()    
    DELETE FROM #par WHERE parid = @IDToDelete

    COMMIT
END
```

And then simply:

```
exec CleanUp 'Alan',1
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I don't know what the ID's will be, there are multiple where clauses in a select statement that build a temp table. So I need to do the above in a complete set-based operation on many rows. Thanks again.

Comment: @Snowy. Right. So you **do need** the real keys, not the surrogates. Put them in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case you could simply use a Cursor. Not the best for performance but looks like this is a downtime-clean up job anyway:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CleanUp
AS
BEGIN

    -- BUILD YOUR TEMP TABLE(S) HERE:
    --
    --

    DECLARE @delete_parent_id int;

    -- SELECT ON TEMP TABLE (AS A CURSOR):
    -- Put your specific Select statement here:
    DECLARE delete_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT parid
    FROM #TEMPTABLE
    WHERE <...> ;


    OPEN delete_cursor;

    BEGIN TRAN
        -- Loop round each selected parent, create new parent, update children and delete old parent.
        FETCH NEXT FROM delete_cursor 
        INTO @delete_parent_id;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO #par VALUES ('Some new Text') --New Parent Row     
            UPDATE #chi SET parid= SCOPE_IDENTITY() where parid = @delete_parent_id   -- Adjust FK ref on child
            DELETE FROM #par WHERE parid = @delete_parent_id -- delete old parent.

            FETCH NEXT FROM delete_cursor 
            INTO @delete_parent_id;
        END

    COMMIT

    CLOSE delete_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE delete_cursor;
END
```