# How to Implement Referential Integrity in Subtypes

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following tables in a relational database:

```
[Sensor]
LocationId [PK / FK -> Location]
SensorNo [PK]

[AnalogSensor]
LocationId [PK/FK -> Sensor]
SensorNo [PK/FK -> Sensor]
UpperLimit
LowerLimit

[SwitchSensor]
LocationId [PK/FK -> Sensor]
SensorNo [PK/FK -> Sensor]
OnTimeLimit

[Reading]
LocationId [PK/FK -> Sensor]
SensorNo [PK/FK -> Sensor]
ReadingDtm [PK]

[ReadingSwitch]
LocationId [PK/FK -> Reading]
SensorNo [PK/FK -> Reading]
ReadingDtm [PK/FK -> Reading]
Switch

[ReadingValue]
LocationId [PK/FK -> Reading]
SensorNo [PK/FK -> Reading]
ReadingDtm [PK/FK -> Reading]
Value

[Alert]
LocationId [PK/FK -> Reading]
SensorNo [PK/FK -> Reading]
ReadingDtm [PK/FK -> Reading]
```

Basically, ReadingSwitch and ReadingValue are subtypes of Reading and SwitchSensor and AnalogSensor are subtypes of Sensor.  A reading can either be a SwitchReading or ValueReading value - it cannot be both, and a Sensor can either be an AnalogSensor or a SwitchSensor.

The only way I've come across to do this so far is [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100309034643/http://consultingblogs.emc.com/davidportas/archive/2007/01/08/Distributed-Keys-and-Disjoint-Subtypes.aspx).

There surely must be a nicer way to do this sort of thing.

The only other way I can think of is to not have sub types but completely expand everything:

```
[SwitchSensor]
LocationId [PK/FK -> Location]
SensorNo [PK]

[AnalogSensor]
LocationId [PK/FK -> Location]
SensorNo [PK]

[SwitchReading]
LocationId [PK/FK -> SwitchSensor]
SensorNo [PK/FK -> SwitchSensor]
ReadingDtm
Switch

[AnalogReading]
LocationId [PK/FK -> AnalogSensor]
SensorNo [PK/FK -> AnalogSensor]
ReadingDtm
Value

[AnalogReadingAlert]
LocationId [PK/FK -> AnalogReading]
SensorNo [PK/FK -> AnalogReading]
ReadingDtm [PK/FK -> AnalogReading]

[SwitchReadingAlert]
LocationId [PK/FK -> SwitchReading]
SensorNo [PK/FK -> SwitchReading]
ReadingDtm [PK/FK -> SwitchReading]
```

Which might not be so bad but I also have tables that reference the Alert table, so they too would have to be duplicated:

```
[AnalogReadingAlertAcknowledgement]
...
[AnalogReadingAlertAction]
...
[SwitchReadingAlartAcknowledgement]
...
[SwitchReadingAlartAction]
```

etc.

Does this problem make any sense to anyone??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

None of that is necessary, especially not the **doubling up the tables**.

### Introduction

Since the Standard for Modelling Relational Databases (IDEF1X) has been in common use for over 25 years (at least in the high quality, high performance end of the market), I use that terminology.  Date & Darwen, <strike>despite</strike><sup>1</sup> consistent with the great work they have done to <strike>progress</strike>suppress the *Relation Model*, they were unaware of IDEF1X until I brought it to their attention in 2009, and thus has a new terminology<sup>2</sup> for the Standard terminology that we have been using for decades. Further, the new terminology does not deal with all the cases, as IDEF1X does.  Therefore I use the established Standard terminology, and avoid new terminology.

- Even the concept of a "distributed key" fails to recognise the underlying ordinary PK::FK Relations, their implementation in SQL, and their power.
- The Relational, and therefore IDEF1X, concept is **Identifiers** and Migration thereof.
- Sure, the vendors are not exactly on the ball, and they have weird things such a "partial Indices" etc, which are completely unnecessary when the basics are understood.  But famous “academics” and “theoreticians” coming up with incomplete new concepts when the concept was standardised and give full treatment 25 years ago ... that, is unexpected and unacceptable.

#### Caveat

IEC/ISO/ANSI SQL barely handles Codd’s 3NF (Date & Darwen’s “5NF”) adequately, and it does not support Basetype-Subtype structures at all; there are no Declarative Constraints for this (and there should be).

- Therefore, in order to enforce the full set of Rules expressed in the Data Model, both Basetype::Subtype and Subtype::Basetype, we have to  fiddle a little with `CHECK CONSTRAINT`s, etc (I avoid using Triggers for a number of reasons).

#### Relief

However, I take all that into account.  In order for me to effectively provide a Data Modelling service on Stack Overflow, without having to preface that with a full discourse, I purposely provide models that can be implemented by capable people, using existing SQL and existing Constraints, to whatever extent they require.  It is already simplified, and contains the common level of enforcement.

We can use both the example graphic in the linked document and your fully IDEF1X-compliant [**Sensor Data Model**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Mark%20DM.pdf)

Readers who are not familiar with the Relational Modelling Standard may find [**IDEF1X Notation**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) useful. Readers who think a database can be mapped to objects, classes, and subclasses are advised that reading further may cause injury.  This is further than Fowler and Ambler have read.

## Implementation of Referential Integrity for Basetype-Subtype

There are two types of Basetype-Subtype structures.

### Exclusive Subtype

Exclusive means there must be one and only one Subtype row for each Basetype row.  In IDEF1X terms, there should be a Discriminator column in the Basetype, which identifies the Subtype row that exists for it.

- For more than two Subtypes, this is demanded, and I implement a Discriminator column.
- For two Subtypes, since this is easily derived from existing data (eg. `Sensor.IsSwitch` is the Discriminator for `Reading`), I do not model an additional explicit Discriminator column for `Reading`.  However, you are free to follow the Standard to the letter and implement a Discriminator.

I will take each aspect in detail.

1. The Discriminator column needs a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to ensure it is within the range of values, eg: `IN ("B", "C", "D")`. `IsSwitch` is a `BIT`, which is 0 or 1, so that is already constrained.
2. Since the PK of the Basetype defines its uniqueness, only one Basetype row will be allowed; no second Basetype row (and thus no second Subtype row) can be inserted.

- Therefore it is overkill, completely redundant, an additional unnecessary Index, to implement an Index such as (PK, Discriminator) in the Basetype, as your link advises.  The uniqueness is in the PK, and therefore the PK plus anything will be unique).
- IDEF1X does not require the Discriminator in the Subtype tables.  In the Subtype, which is again constrained by the uniqueness of its PK, as per the model, if the Discriminator was implemented as a column in that table, every row in it will have the same value for the Discriminator (every Book will be "B"; every `ReadingSwitch` will be an `IsSwitch`).  Therefore it is absurd to implement the Discriminator as a column in the Subtype.  And again, completely redundant, an additional unnecessary Index, to implement an Index such as (PK, Discriminator) in the Subtype: the uniqueness is in the PK, and therefore the PK plus anything will be unique).
- The method identified in the link is a ham-fisted and bloated (massive data duplication for no purpose) way of implementing Referential Integrity.  There is probably a good reason the author has not seen that construct anywhere else. It is a basic failure to understand SQL and to use it *as it is* effectively. These "solutions" are typical of people who follow a dogma "SQL can't do ..." and thus are blind to what SQL can do. The horrors that result from Fowler and Ambler's blind "methods" are even worse.

3. The Subtype PK is also the FK to the Basetype, that is all that is required, to ensure that the Subtype does not exist without a parent Basetype.

- Therefore for any given PK, whichever Basetype-Subtype is inserted first will succeed; and whichever Basetype-Subtype is attempted after that, will fail.  Therefore there is nothing to worry about in the Subtype table (a second Basetype row or a second Subtype row for the same PK is prevented).
  .

4. The SQL `CHECK CONSTRAINT` is limited to checking the *inserted row*.  We need to check the inserted row *against other rows*, either in the same table, or in another table. Therefore a 'User Defined' Function is required.

- Write a simple UDF that will check for existence of the PK **and** the Discriminator in the Basetype, and return 1 if `EXITS` or 0 if `NOT EXITS`.  You will need one UDF per Basetype (not per Subtype).
- In the Subtype, implement a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` that calls the UDF, using the PK (which is both the Basetype and the Subtype) and the Discriminator *value*.
- I have implemented this in scores of large, real world databases, on different SQL platforms.  Here is the 'User Defined' [**Function Code**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Tutorial/ValidateExclusive_fn.sql), and the [**DDL Code**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Tutorial/Subtype_CHECK.sql) for the objects it is based on.
- This particular syntax and code is tested on Sybase ASE 15.0.2 (they are very conservative about SQL Standards compliance).
- I am aware that the limitations on 'User Defined' Functions are different for every SQL platform.  However, this is the simplest of the simple, and AFAIK every platform allows this construct.  (No idea what the Non-SQLs do.)
- yes, of course this clever little technique can be used implement any non-trivial data rule that you can draw in a Data Model.  In particular, to overcome the limitations of SQL.  Note my caution to avoid two-way Constraints (circular references).

5. Therefore the `CHECK CONSTRAINT` in the Subtype, ensures that the PK plus the **correct** Discriminator exists in Basetype.  Which means that **only** that Subtype exists for the Basetype (the PK).

- Any subsequent attempt to insert *another* Subtype (ie. break the Exclusive Rule) will fail because the PK+Discriminator does not exist in the Basetype.
- Any subsequent attempt to insert another row of the same Subtype is prevented by the uniqueness of its PK Constraint.

6. The only bit that is missing (not mentioned in the link) is the Rule "every Basetype must have at least one Subtype" is not enforced.  This is easily covered in Transactional code (I do **not** advise Constraints going in two directions, or Triggers); use the right tool for the job.

### Non-exclusive Subtype

The Basetype (parent) can host more than one Subtype (child)

1. There is no single Subtype to be identified.

- The Discriminator does not apply to Non-exclusive Subtypes.
- The existence of a Subtype is identified by performing an existence check on the Subtype table, using the Basetype PK.

2. Simply exclude the `CHECK CONSTRAINT` that calls the UDF above.

- The `PRIMARY KEY`, `FOREIGN KEY`, and the usual Range `CHECK CONSTRAINT`s, adequately support all requirements for Non-exclusive Subtypes.

#### Reference

For further detail; a diagrammatic overview including details; and the distinction between Subtypes and Optional Column tables, refer to this [**Subtype document**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf).

#### Note

1. I, too, was taken in by C J Date's and Hugh Darwen's constant references to "furthering" the *Relational Model*.  After many years of interaction, based on the mountain of consistent evidence, I have concluded that their work is in fact, a debasement of it.  They have done nothing to further Dr E F Codd's seminal work, the *Relational Model*, and everything to damage and suppress it.
2. They have private definitions for Relational terms, which of course severely hinders any communication.  They have new terminology for terms we have had since 1970, in order to appear that they have "invented" it.

### Response to Comment

<sup>This section can be skipped by all readers who did not comment.</sup>

Unfortunately, some people are so schooled in doing things the wrong way, at massive additional cost, that even when directed clearly in the right way, they cannot understand it.  Perhaps that is why proper education cannot be substituted with a Question-and Answer format.

> Sam:
> I’ve noticed that this approach doesn't prevent someone from using `UPDATE` to change a Basetype's discriminator value. How could that be prevented? The `FOREIGN KEY` + duplicate Discriminator column in subtypes approach seems to overcome this.

Yes. This Method doesn't prevent someone using `UPDATE` to change a Key, or a column in some unrelated table, or headaches, either. It answers a specific question, and nothing else. If you wish to prevent certain DML commands or whatever, use the SQL facility that is designed for that purpose. All that is way beyond the scope of this question. Otherwise every answer has to address every unrelated issue.

Answer.  Since we should be using [**Open Architecture Standards**](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Application%20Architecture/Open%20Architecture.pdf), available since 1993, all changes to the db are via ACID Transactions, only. That means direct `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`, to all tables are prohibited; the data retains Integrity and Consistency (ACID terminology). Otherwise, sure, you have a mess, such as your eg. and the consequences.  The proponents of this method do not understand Transactions, they understand only single file `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`.

Further, the FK+Duplicate D+Duplicate Index (and the massive cost therein !) does nothing of the sort, I don't know where you got "seems" from.

> dtheodor:
> This question is about referential integrity. Referential integrity doesn't mean "check that the reference is valid on insert and the forget about it". It means "maintain the validity of the reference forever". The duplicate discriminator + FK method guarantees this integrity, your UDF approach does not. It's without question that `UPDATE`s should not break the reference.

The problem here is two-fold.  First, you need basic education in *other areas* regarding Relational Databases and Open Architecture Standards. Again, it is best to open a new question here, so a complete answer to that other area of Relational Databases can be provided.

OK, short answer, that really belongs in another question **How is the Discriminator in Exclusive Subtypes Protected from an Invalid UPDATE?**

1. Clarity.  Yes, *Referential integrity doesn't mean "check that the reference is valid on insert and the forget about it”*.  I didn’t say that it meant that either.

- Referential Integrity means the References in the database `FOREIGN KEY` has Integrity with the `PRIMARY KEY` that it references.
- Declarative Referential Integrity means the *declared* References in the database ...
  `CONSTRAINT` FOREIGN KEY `... REFERENCES ...`
  `CONSTRAINT CHECK ...`
  are maintained by the RDBMS platform and not by the application code.
- It does **not** mean "maintain the validity of the reference forever” either.

2. The original question regards RI for Subtypes, and I have answered it, providing DRI.

- The point that massively inefficient structures and duplicated tables, are not required, must be emphasised.

3. Your question does not regard RI or DRI.
4. Your question, although asked incorrectly, because you are expecting the Method to provide what the Method does not provide, and you do not understand that your requirement is fulfilled by other means, is **How is the Discriminator in Exclusive Subtypes Protected from an Invalid UPDATE ?**
5. The answer is, use the Open Architecture Standards that we should be using since 1993.  That prevents **all** invalid `UPDATE`s. Do please read the linked documents, and understand them, your concern is a non-issue, it does not exist. That is the short answer.
6. But you did not understand the short answer, so I will explain it here.

- No one is allowed to walk up to the database and change a column here or a value there.  Using either SQL directly or an app that uses SQL directly.  If that were allowed, you will not have a secured database.
- All updates (lower case) to the database (including multi-row `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`) are implemented as ACID SQL Transactions.  And nothing but Transactions.  The **set** of Transactions constitute the **Database API**, that is exposed to any application that uses the database.

  - SQL has ACID Transactions.  Non-SQL databases do not have Transactions. Proponents of these database systems know absolutely nothing about Transactions, let alone Open Architecture.  Their Non-architecture is a monolithic stack.  And a “database” that gets refactored every month.
- Since the only Transactions that you write will insert the basetype+subtype in a single Transaction, as a single Logical Unit of Work, the Integrity (data Integrity, not Referential Integrity) of the basetype::subtype relation is maintained, and maintained within the database.  Therefore all updates to the database will be Valid, there will not be any Invalid updates.
- Since you are not so stupid as to write code that `UPDATE`s the Discriminator column in a single row without the attendant `DELETE Previous_Subtype`, place it in a Transaction, and `GRANT EXEC` permission for it to user `ROLES`, there will not be an Invalid Discriminator anywhere in the database.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: The Switch Sensors has different parameters to the Analog Sensors so I've been considering splitting them up (though not sure if it's worth it).  On top of that, a LoggerSensor is only ever Analog.  I could just put all the parameters in Sensor and use whichever are appropriate based on the IsSwitch column.  For example "UpperLimit" and "LowerLimit" are AnalogSensor parameters and don't relate to SwitchSensors.. SwitchSensor has "OnTimeLimit" (i.e. time the switch can be ON before an alarm occurs).

Comment: Good answer, though I'm not convinced that the "UDF+CHECK" approach is superior to the "include the Discriminator in PK/FK including subtype tables" one. Both are workarounds that highlight what SQL needs but will never have: distributed inclusion dependency constraints, multiple assignment operators, etc.

Comment: @onedaywhen. Oh dear. In that case, you must think that (a) one **additional column** plus one **additional index** per Subtype, plus (b) one **additional index** in the Supertype, with (c) their consequent overhead, and (d) the impeded inserts/deletes (each of which now have two additional indices), is equal to or better than the absence of (a)(b)(c)(d). The UDF+CHECK and the PK+FK REFERENCE are equivalent, and excluded.  In which case you are operating on opinion, not on the laws of physics or computer science. In which case I would not try to convince you of anything relating to them.

Comment: I agree, and I stated that this implements constraints that SQL should provide declaratively. But I would not call this a workaround, that means something else.  An Extension, yes. And we need many of them to support 5NF fully.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: "The UDF+CHECK and the PK+FK REFERENCE are equivalent" -- in terms of performance? Really? Assuming SQL and therefore an optimizer, how would I know whether it can use the UDF? Assuming Full SQL-92, you don't need the UDF because a CHECK can contain a subquery but consider that most SQL products would have serious problems adapting their optimizers to cope.

Comment: @onedaywhen. 1) No idea where you get your info from. The [SQL ANSI-92 spec](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) Levelling Rules (1) (a) on p282 specifically state that a CHECK constraint cannot contain a subquery.  Further, none of the vendors providing ANSI SQL-92 allow subqueries in CHECK constraints. Which um explains why an UDF is required. 2) how I write. I was not aware that I should consult you before I post. Make sure you update the FAQ, so that all of use can follow your guidelines. 3) the comments do not allow a full explanation of resource arithmetic.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: Take a look at what I said: "Assuming Full SQL-92..." Now take another look at p282 of the spec: "The following restrictions apply for Intermediate SQL..." That's right, you've confused "Intermediate" and "Full". So yes, perhaps should consult me before you post but let's keep it between ourselves, eh? ;) P.S. MS Access supports subqueries in `CHECK` constraints but I don't consider it a proper SQL.

Comment: @onedaywhen. The simple unconfused fact is, most SQLs (incl OP's PostgreSQL) do not allow subqueries in CHECK constraints; and most SQLs have UDFs, therefore the UDF is required.  All this running around in circles in the comments and getting confused about your confusion is all yours, it has nothing to do with (a) the question or (b) the answer or (c) me.  To find out if your SQL allows UDFs, just ask a question on SO, you will get the popular view.

Comment: By the way, I think your example UDF could be more generalised by not using `SELECT COALESCE(1, 0)` since it doesn't work in Microsoft SQL Server for me.

Comment: I've noticed that this approach doesn't prevent someone from using `UPDATE` to change a supertype's discriminator value. How could that be prevented? The foreign key + duplicate discriminator column in subtypes approach seems to overcome this.

Comment: @Sam. (1) You are welcome. (2) The code specifically informs you that it is for Sybase ASE.  That means, as a coder, you need to implement the syntax required for your platform. (3) Yes. This Method doesn't prevent someone using UPDATE to change a Key, or a column in some unrelated table, or headaches, either. It answers a specific question, and nothing else. If you wish to prevent certain DML commands or whatever, use the SQL facility that is designed for that purpose.  All that is way beyond the scope of this question. Otherwise every answer has to address every unrelated isuue.  Contd.

Comment: @Sam. Eg. if Open Architecture Standards are used, **all** changes to the db are via ACID Transactions, only. That means direct INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, to **all** tables are prevented; the data retains Integrity and Consistency (ACID term). Otherwise, sure, you have a bleeding mess, such as your eg. and the consequences. Again, out-of-scope. If you need more details, please **open a new question**, and I will answer it in detail.  (4) The FK+Duplicate D+Duplicate Index does nothing of the sort., I don't know where you got "seems" from.  Those freaks do not understand Transactions.

Comment: This question is about referential integrity. Referential integrity doesn't mean "check that the reference is valid on insert and the forget about it". It means "maintain the validity of the reference forever". The duplicate discriminator + FK method guarantees this integrity, your UDF approach does not. It's without question that UPDATEs should not break the reference

Answer (score 1):

The second option is also fraught with issues - e.g. for Sensors (and assuming that SensorNo is a surrogate key), because you don't have a base table, the SensorNo surrogate is either not unique between the sub class tables, unless you use a klugey mechanism to issue keys across all the sub-class tables (or use a guid).

This would be amplified if you had user interface which 'combines' different types of sensors, e.g. a list showing a union of Analog and Switch sensors.

I would recommend that you stay with your first pattern, and then encapsulate the insertion and maintenance of these tables with well tested, transactional code.

e.g. Create Insertion Procedures for the various SubTables, which insert the respective base and subclass records under a unit of work. You can go further by then revoking INSERT privileges on ANY of the tables thus forcing insertion via the SPROC's.

You could also run a daily integrity report which checked that there were no violations of your inheritance structure.

Comment: This is a Relational database, not a bunch of object classes/subclasses.  Despite what Fowlers states, there are important differences. Agree with your points re security.