# SQL-DBDL How to constrain a Superclass to participate in Subclasses?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, constraints

I have been looking for a way to constrain records of a superclass to participate in one of its subclasses records, I believe it is called participation {Mandatory OR}. I found some example on how to use CONSTRAINT CHECK but only to constrain multiplicity.

Although I can guard this using the application logic that is going to use the database I prefer having a constraint set up using the database definition language.

Is it possible to do that ?

Below I have uploaded an image with an illustration of what I am trying to achieve, as you can see in the message table there is a message that does not match neither UserMessage nor GroupMessage.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done *declaratively* without deferred foreign keys, which MySQL doesn't support.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12261722/533120), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9178524/533120) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12366217/533120).

Comment: In other words I have to rely on my application logic, right ? Thanks.

Comment: @twimB Yes, if you stay with MySQL.

Comment: @twimB BTW, I used the term "application logic" in a wider sense, that includes triggers and stored procedures.