# How to add a reference to a model in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need a model to have an `external_id` field, but that `id` can come from different models.

For example I have a `Customers` model, and the customer can be either an organization or an invididual. The `Organizations` and `Individuals` models are obviously different, and I need to point to to either of those.

My idea would be to have an `external_id` field in `Customers`, and then a `type` field with that would allow me to point the `external_id` to the proper model.

Is this possible in Sequelize?

How would I define this relationship in Sequelize and query it afterwards?

Comment: Can you put how you have define your models until now?

Comment: @Ellebkey This is theoretical, I don't have any model definitions

Comment: Well actually you have two ways to do the associations for this. 1. You can define Customer association with `belongsTo(models.Organization);`. Same with the Individuals. This way you will create two foreign keys for each model. 2. Or, you can `hasMany(models.Organization)`. This way you'll create a foreign key refering the Customer model. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255731/supertype-subtype-database-design) actually explain the SuperType- SubType Models.

Comment: But what if I want to add more customer types in the future? Adding more fields is not really a scalable solution.

Comment: Second option is better cuz you add the customer reference on each new model