# Database structure for ticketing system

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I would like to create a ticketing PHP application, but I stucked at the planning of database structure.

I would have completely different type of ticket templates (user / shared folder / end-device processes etc..) which require different inputs.

**The question** is that, shoud I store them in one table, or should I create a separate table for every ticket group?

If I store them in one table, there will be many empty fields in the table because different tickets use different fields.

I think the common fields would be the `unique ID`, `status` and `responsible person` only, the others are different.

My **preferred solution** would be that if I store them in separate tables with the required fields only.

But this would cause **troubles** in a simple SELECT query when I would like to list every tickets. If I join them together during the query it will create a result table with many empty fields because of the difference between the structure of the tables which is not optimal. To avoid this I should run separate queries for every table which is not so simple.

What way would you choose? Could you please give me an advice?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should look up data normalization. At the very least, you should show the structure of the different ticket data sets. I'm sure there are things in common between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never put different entities in the same table. Yes, they have some common fields, but a bunch of empty columns is a clear signal that such design should be avoided, and good sign is that you are aware of it :) If we jump at the moment from the database world into application world with OO patterns and classes, this would be typically solved by inheritance (is-a relationship). How to enforce this in SQL (specifically, MySQL)?

Divide data in separate tables with one common table, let's call it `ticket_template`, that will contain common fields (you mentioned `template_id`, `status` and `responsible person`). Other tables, such as `user_template` will be created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_template(
    user_template_id int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES ticket_template(template_id)
    ...
);
```

and they should keep fields specific to *that particular entity*. If you want a common report, write multiple SQL selects and show their results one after another. If you want all of them together, just list common fields together.

Caveat - this design does not prevent confused user to insert a `ticket_template` that is not related to any of concrete templates (such as `user_template`), or that is related to many of them (more than 1). If the database supports deferred constraints (MySQL unfortunately doesn't), that can be enforced too, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255731/supertype-subtype-database-design/12261722#12261722).

Comment: Thank you! This was very useful for me and I will follow your advices.

Comment: `a bunch of empty columns is a clear signal that such design should be avoided` That's not true. That's a sound and common approach for implementing inheritance in relational databases, it's called table-per-hierarchy, or TPH.