# Database design, How to reduce the data redundancy for different column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have an existing table which requires different columns for different record. do I need to split it into multiple tables to reduce the redundancy?

Table1:

```
productId   typeId  commonAttr1 commonAttr2 attrA1  attrB1 attrB2
_________________________________________________________________
1           1       1Avalue1    1Avalue2    value1      
2           1       1Avalue1    1Avalue2    value2
3           2       2Bvalue1    2Bvalue2            value3  value4
4           2       2Bvalue3    2Bvalue4            value5  value6
```

The "attrA1" is only for recored with typeId=1, "attrB1" and "attrB2" are only for records with typeId=2, "commonAttr1", "commonAttr2" are for both.

There might be 3 options:

#### 1. Do not change. accept the data redundancy.

#### 2. Move "attrA1" to new table2, move "attrB1","attrB2" to new table3.It'll be like:

Table1:

```
productId   typeId  commonAttr1 commonAttr2
___________________________________________
1           1       1Avalue1    1Avalue2
2           1       1Avalue1    1Avalue2 
3           2       2Bvalue1    2Bvalue2           
4           2       2Bvalue3    2Bvalue4
```

Table2:

```
productId   attrA1
__________________
1           value1
2           value2
```

Table3:

```
productId   attrB1   attrB2
___________________________
3           value3   value4
4           value5   value6
```

#### 3.Create a new table to store the column as Key/Value

Table1:

```
productId   typeId  commonAttr1 commonAttr2
___________________________________________
1           1       1Avalue1    1Avalue2
2           1       1Avalue1    1Avalue2 
3           2       2Bvalue1    2Bvalue2           
4           2       2Bvalue3    2Bvalue4
```

Table2:

```
productId  typeId   key       value
____________________________________
1          1        attrA1    value1
2          1        attrA1    value2 
3          2        attrB1    value3           
3          2        attrB2    value4
4          2        attrB1    value5
4          2        attrB2    value6
```

Which option is better or is there any other solution? Personally I suppose option 2 is better.

Comment: It depends on why you want to do this schema refactoring. What is the issue you are facing with the existing table ?

Comment: [Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is what you're attempting and it's always a good idea to keep in mind when designing a DB (although you can overdo it). I'd go with option 2 too, but introduce another table just for the common attributes with it's own id column and your actual transaction table would just have a productId, TypeId and a CommonAttrId

Comment: Thanks, Ashwin, for option2, I kept table1 with the commonattr columns, just move the others to table2 and table3.

Comment: @AshwinNair Restructuring involving NULLs or EAVis not normalization, which is about replacing a table by projections of it that inner join back to it.

Comment: Please specify the queries you will be performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a schema in which common attributes are stored in one table an the other ones are stored in their dependent tables it's called a model (base)type/subtype design (or a model for inheritance). In this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896831/how-to-implement-referential-integrity-in-subtypes/4898314#4898314) you would fine how to correctly implement it (in order to keep referential integrity)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**4** One table with  `productId`, `typeId`, `commonAttr1`, `commonAttr2`, `json`

where that last column is a JSON rendering of the other key-value pairs.

EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) schema is problematic; sometimes #4 is a useful compromise.  [More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).